# How to register for 32-Bit COM interop using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, com-interop, visual-studio-2022

I am having difficulty registering a C# component for COM interop using Visual Studio 2022. I thought I understood the problem, but even so, I have failed to get it working.

This is the basic problem:

- Visual Studio 2022 is a 64-Bit application
- When you build with Visual Studio 2022 it invokes the 64-Bit version of MSBuild
- The 64-Bit version of MSBuild invokes the 64-Bit version of RegAsm, which registers the component as a 64-Bit COM component

Since most COM-Based applications in the real world are 32-Bit applications, this is most likely not what you want.

Although this is clearly by design, I find it to be an unfortunate design choice and I have opened an [issue in the Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/register-for-com-interop-broken-in-visual-studio-2/1599406). If you agree with me, it might help gave the issue an up-vote.

---

*Attempted workaround:*

Following the instructions on [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild/) I thought it was going to be easy to update our projects by:

- unchecking the option "Register for COM interop"
- replacing it with a post-build-event to run the 32 bit version of RegAsm

This is the command that I have defined as a post-build-event:

```
"%Windir%Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe” “$(TargetPath)” /codebase
```

This leads to the error MSB3073, and the text "The command ... exited with code 123".

In full the output line is:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5710,5): error MSB3073: The command ""%Windir%Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe” “C:\CS3\Output\Applications\interop\McDaMBusTimer.dll” /codebase" exited with code 123.
```

I have tried several variations of the command, but I haven't found a definition which works.

---

Does anybody know the exact command that I have to enter as a post-build-step?

Comment: Do you get some more information when you run the command manually in a command line? (maybe there's a verbose option?)

Comment: "most COM-Based applications in the real world are 32-Bit applications" is not that true. There are now lots of 64-bit COM apps (like all Microsoft ones for starter). Anyway unchecking + post build should work, but the command should be "%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" (with a \ after windir%)

Comment: Inserting a \ certainly makes sense. Unfortunately, the result is exactly the same. Inserting the exact path c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe also produces the same result.

Comment: It should work. Note the quotes in your question seem funny. Or post a reproducing project so we can make sure what fails.

Comment: I may be wrong about COM-Based applications. My assumption was, that COM is 25 to 30 year old technology, most COM projects have old roots, and they are not going to move to 64-Bit.

Comment: Here is a [test project](https://www.jollans.com/COMVisibleTest.zip)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, you quotes are incorrect, you use two ” instead of " (this is not the same character). As for COM, yes it's 30 years old, but still widely used in 64-bit Windows (newer WinRT is also COM based) and every major worldwide app: Office, Adobe, Autodesk, Matlab, etc. and there are new COM projects every day. COM basically follows all 64-bit application upgrades.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that is very observant of you. Thank you very much. I swear you cannot see that in the Visual Studio property pages. I was able to see it when I opened the .csproj file in an editor. I originally copied the command from [the page I mentioned](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild/)in the question. That page appears to contain the wrong characters as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was quite stupid and entirely my own fault.

The correct command is

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" "$(TargetPath)" /codebase
```

If you need to generate a type library file, you should use the command

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" "$(TargetPath)" /codebase /tlb
```

If you want to edit it directly into the project file, you can use

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>"%25windir%25\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" "$(TargetPath)" /codebase /tlb</PostBuildEvent>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

As Simon Mourier pointed out, I was originally using the wrong inverted commas. It turns out that I was using
the [Right Double Quotation Mark, Unicode 0x201D](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201D) instead of the
normal [Quotation Mark, Unicode 0x0022](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022).

In my opinion, you cannot see the difference in the project properties in Visual Studio.

The reason I had this error, was that I originally copied the command

```
“%Windir%Microsoft.NETFramework[64]v4.0.xxxxxregasm” “$(TargetPath)”
```

from [this Microsoft page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild/). If you look closely you can see the difference.

Comment: The `25` is a typo? `<PostBuildEvent>"%25windir%25\M...`

Comment: Hex 25 is the ASCII code for %. This is how Visual Studio writes the command into the project file. In the UI, it is displayed as %.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution is to use the MSBuild `RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture` property with a value of `x86` to force the COM assembly registration task (or `regasm`) to register the project's assembly in the 32-bit registry. If you want to force 64-bit COM assembly registration use a value of `x64` for `RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture`. I added the `RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture` property with a value of `x86` to my project file and it worked. The assembly was now registered in the 32-bit registry keys, and not in the 64-bit registry keys.

Apparently this happens if the `Platform` MSBuild property is `AnyCPU`. In which case the COM assembly registration defaults to the same bitness of the MSBuild runtime. For Visual Studio 2022 that means a 64-bit MSBuild runtime. If `Platform` were `x86` then the COM assembly registration would also be 32-bit without setting the `RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture` property. I can't confirm that because I haven't tried this approach.

This is pointed out by the resolution to the issue in the [Microsoft Developer Community bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/register-for-com-interop-broken-in-visual-studio-2/1599406#TPIN-N1649171) linked in the original question.

As far as I can see `RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture` is not documented anywhere else.

Comment: It seems like setting the target to x86 instead of AnyCPU also will work, and then the RegisterAssemblyMSBuildArchitecture is not needed. I'm not sure which is necessarily better though I think I prefer doing it through the GUI as it is more discoverable.